# Incorrect syntax near '10'

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
int ID;
ID = Int32.Parse(Combo_Stu.SelectedValue.ToString());
double a = double.Parse(Txt_Ins.Text);
string date = dtp_Stu.Value.ToString();
SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Instalment_Billing(ID,Pay_Date, Fees) VALUES (" + ID + "," + **date** + "," + a + ")", con);
con.Open();
sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Incorrect syntax near '10'
I am getting this error in date 
guess pls help me

Comment: Better check the answer from Pax as good answer since he solved your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is probably that your date is unquoted, but the real solution to this problem is to use a parameterized query.

Answer (score 5):

*Whenever* you get an error in a line like:

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Instalment_Billing(" +
    "ID,Pay_Date, Fees) VALUES (" + ID + "," + date + "," + a + ")", con);
```

you should immediately insert some code to print it out and check whether it's valid SQL:

```
Console.WriteLine ("INSERT INTO Instalment_Billing(" +
    "ID,Pay_Date, Fees) VALUES (" + ID + "," + date + "," + a + ")");
```

or:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("INSERT INTO Instalment_Billing" +
    "(ID,Pay_Date, Fees) VALUES (" + ID + "," + date + "," + a + ")");
```

This should show you *exactly* where your problem lies. Most likely insertions of dates should use strings of the format `'yyyy.mm.dd'` or something similar so you should, at a bare minimum:

- quote the date string (`... + ",'" + date + "'," + ...`).
- ensure that its format is okay (I'm not sure what `ToString()` will give you off the top of my head but I would think, given that you posted this today and it's not the tenth month or tenth day of the month, that it's probably something like `yy-mm-dd` and the unquoted 10 from 2010 is causing you grief).

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            int ID;
            ID = Int32.Parse(Combo_Stu.SelectedValue.ToString());
            double a = double.Parse(Txt_Ins.Text);
            string date = dtp_Stu.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Instalment_Billing (ID, Pay_date, Fees) VALUES (1, CONVERT(DATETIME, '"+ date +"', 102), 100)", con);
            con.Open();
            sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

Thanks a lot



i changed my input string to yyyy-MM-dd and it worked